# How many ways are there to execute system command in C program for windows

Tags: c

I am using MS visual studio 2008, for C coding.

I know we can use
"`int system(const char *command)`" to execute commands.

Is there any other method to execute system commands in C program.
Also I need to store output of executed command in a variable.

`system()` function execute command and send output to `stdout` , is there any way to read from `stdout` and store in variable.

So my ultimate goal is to execute system command in C program for windows (using visual studio) and store output of that command in a variable.
Any suggestions ?

Comment: In standard C? There's no other way. If you want platform-specific functions to be able to read the output of the command, then do some research about the higher-level `_popen` and lower-level `CreateProcess` functions. Both are Windows specific functions.

Comment: Use system() and pipe the output into a temp file,  Open and read the temp file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Standard C libraries give you only one way to execute external command in OS, so use `int system(const char *command)`.

You can save output of this command to text file, and then read this file from you program.

For example:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define TMP_FILE_NAME "TMP_FOLDER_CONTENT.txt"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    system("dir C:\* > "TMP_FILE_NAME);
    FILE * fdir = fopen(TMP_FILE_NAME, "r");
    char buff[100];
    if (fdir)
    {
        while (1) {
            if (fgets(buff, 100, fdir) == NULL) break;
            printf("%s", buff);
        }
    }
    fclose(fdir);
    remove(TMP_FILE_NAME);
    return 0;
}
```

Where `dir` is a program to be executed, `C:\*` - argument of the program, and `>` - redirection of standard output for that command after which filename `TMP_FOLDER_CONTENT.txt` will be substituted.

Also you can check returned value, as:

```
int errorcode = system("dir C:\* > "TMP_FILE_NAME);
printf("Command executed and returned a value %d\n", errorcode);
```

or taking into account command you use, change the logic of your program, e.g.:

```
int errorcode = system("dir C:\* > "TMP_FILE_NAME);
if( errorcode )
{
   return errorcode;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Alternatively, you could use pipes in C++, for example as shown in the answer to question [How to execute a command and get output of command within C++ using POSIX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478898/how-to-execute-a-command-and-get-output-of-command-within-c-using-posix)

Comment: Is there any way so i dont need extra file, I mean, write output directly to variable.

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot to set your program as command line command output receiver instead of `stdout`, and more problem is in the way of execution of `system` command - in my example it is synchronous command execution and next command can be executed only after system is completed and returned a value

Comment: @AshishRana I updated the answer with reference to similar question - it can help, I suppose

Answer (score 0):

you can do as @VolAnd said or also if you don't care about/don't want the output of the command to be in `stdout` and you also don't want anything else to be printed to `stdout` you can use [freopen](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/freopen/) to set stdout to a file of your choice.